# Using reflection to compare a property value to a string representation of that value

Tags: c#, reflection

I have searched and have come close, but can't quite get my head around what I need to do next.  So I have a function that takes my object and a string.

The string has the format of "property=value";  So I split the string at the = sign into 2 strings, prop and value.  Now I would like to then compare the same property in my object to the string.  So I have something like this:

- Clarification Edit:
  I suppose tostring() would work, I guess what I was after is the other way around. Because the actual property value type may be bool, datetime, int or string (and maybe others, but no custom objects) I was thinking I somehow needed to cast or convert value to the correct type and compare.
- 2nd Clarification.  For those that asked, the context is that I am try to create a simple user definable rule system to evaluate data.  Since the data is entered my humans, my biggest concern is that string represent of other types my not compare the same way as if they were actually those types for example 1.00 should = 1.0 if they are decimal types but won't if they are string types.

  ```
  private static bool evaluateCriteria(string s, Client o){

      bool evaluation = false;

      string prop = s.Split('=')[0];
      string value = s.Split('=')[1];

      var propvalue = (o).GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(o, null);  

      //ok so not I want to compare value to propvalue, but don't know how
      // evaluation = (value == propvalue);


      return evaluation;

  }
  ```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for posting. Please clarify what it is you want to achieve and have a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want but I think it is this. Comparing the two string values

```
return string.Compare(value, propvalue.ToString()) == 0;
```

Comment: this is probably the easiest way.  Though I guess my concern is that different string representation wouldn't match though if in the correct type they would for example "1.00" != "1.0" but System.Decimal 1.00 == 1.0

Comment: If you are expecting numbers you could first check to see if the values are numerical using double.TryParse(string, out double) methods

Comment: I would be expecting various types.  I think comparing as string is the best answer and I will just take care to standardize the users input when they create the rule.

Comment: I think I like this answer, though not exactly what I wanted, it lead my train of thought to an acceptable conclusion. I can "switch" based on the reflected property type and then use tryparse so I can correctly compare values with in the proper type.

Answer (score 0):

Change your reflection code to:

```
var propvalue = (o).GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(o, null).ToString();
```

If the value you are looking for is in a special format you may need to do some formatting on it to ensure it matches the format.

You should probably also provide some more context in the question as it is quite vague on what you are trying to achieve and there may be a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you care what type the property actually returns?

If it evaluates to string, you should be able to do something simple like

```
return value == propvalue.ToString();
```

Maybe I'm missing something...